# Запуск py файла с дополнительными опциями (аргументами)

Tags: python, python-3.x, аргументы

Как сделать что бы можно было указать опцию к запуску .py файла.
Например: `python3 main.py -safemode`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: sys.argv или argparser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

if sys.argv[1] == '-safemode':
    print('safe mode!')
else:
    print('no safe mode!')
```